Discord bot not realizing it has command
My discord bot does not show the commands I have added to the Event listener. It only shows older ones and two that aren't even in my code.
I have tried reinviting the bot to my server and turned off Slash commands on my server for a day
as well as added a temp command.
My Command manager looks like this:
package com.recon.commands;

import com.recon.services.DatabaseService;
import com.recon.services.MusicService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Guild;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.interaction.command.SlashCommandInteractionEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static com.recon.DiscordBot.jda;
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CommandManager extends ListenerAdapter {

    private final AddTrack addTrack ;

    private final DisplayQueue displayQueue ;

    private final SkipTrack skipTrack ;

    private final JoinChannel joinChannel;

    private final SetBotChannel setBotChannel ;

    private final ViewGameCards viewGameCards;

    private final CreateGameCard createGameCard;

     private final DeleteGameCard deleteGameCard;

     private final GetWebLink getWebLink;



    @Override
    public void onSlashCommandInteraction(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
      String commandName = event.getName();
      try {
          switch (CommandNames.valueOf(commandName)) {
              case addtrack:
                  addTrack.execute(event);
                  break;
              case skiptrack:
                  skipTrack.execute(event);
                  break;
              case displayqueue:
                  displayQueue.execute(event);
                  break;
              case joinchannel:
                  joinChannel.execute(event);
                  break;
              case setbotchannel:
                  setBotChannel.execute(event);
                  break;
              case viewallgamecards:
                  viewGameCards.execute(event);
                  break;
              case creategamecard:
                   createGameCard.execute(event);
                  break;
              case deletegamecard:
                  deleteGameCard.execute(event);
                  break;
              case getweblink:
                  getWebLink.execute(event);
                  break;
          }
      }catch (NullPointerException e){

          log.info("Something went wrong wille executing command :" + e.getMessage() );

      }

    }
}



My command factory looks like this:
package com.recon.commands;

import com.recon.data.GuildDataMap;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.commands.build.CommandData;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.commands.build.Commands;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.recon.DiscordBot.databaseService;

@Component
public class CommandFactory {

    public List<CommandData> commandData = new ArrayList<>();


    public CommandFactory(AddTrack addTrack,DisplayQueue displayQueue,SkipTrack skipTrack,JoinChannel joinChannel,SetBotChannel setBotChannel,ViewGameCards viewGameCards,CreateGameCard createGameCard, DeleteGameCard deleteGameCard, GetWebLink getWebLink) {
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(addTrack.name(), addTrack.description()).addOptions(addTrack.options()));
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(skipTrack.name(), addTrack.description()));
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(displayQueue.name(), displayQueue.description()));
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(joinChannel.name(), joinChannel.description()));
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(setBotChannel.name(), setBotChannel.description()));
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(viewGameCards.name(), viewGameCards.description()));
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(createGameCard.name(),createGameCard.description()).addOptions(createGameCard.options()));
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(deleteGameCard.name(), deleteGameCard.description()).addOptions(deleteGameCard.options()));
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(getWebLink.name(), getWebLink.description()));
    }



    public void add(ICommand command){
        commandData.add(Commands.slash(command.name(), command.description()).addOptions(command.options()));
    }

}


I create my Jda Like this
package com.recon;

import com.recon.commands.CommandManager;
import com.recon.data.GuildDataMap;
import com.recon.def.BotChannel;
import com.recon.def.GuildData;
import com.recon.listeners.Listener;
import com.recon.repo.BotChannelRepo;
import com.recon.services.DatabaseService;
import com.recon.services.GameCardService;
import com.recon.services.ReactionListener;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.requests.GatewayIntent;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DiscordBot {

    public static JDA jda;
    public static DatabaseService databaseService;

    public static GuildDataMap guildDataMap;
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    @SneakyThrows
    public JDA createJDA(CommandManager commandManager, ReactionListener reactionListener) {
        jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("Dont want to leak my token")
                .addEventListeners(reactionListener)
                .addEventListeners(commandManager)
                .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT)
                .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS)
                .setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE)
                .setActivity(Activity.of(Activity.ActivityType.WATCHING, "The Matrix"))
                .build();
        guildDataMap = new GuildDataMap(databaseService);
        return jda;
    }

    @SneakyThrows

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscordBot.class);
    }


    public static void displayAllBeans() {
        String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String beanName : allBeanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
}

And the command interface looks like this:
package com.recon.commands;

import com.recon.services.MusicService;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.interaction.command.SlashCommandInteractionEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.commands.SlashCommandInteraction;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.commands.build.OptionData;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.commands.build.SlashCommandData;

import java.util.List;

public interface ICommand {

    String name();

    String description();

    List<OptionData> options();

    void execute(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event);


}


This is the command names Enum
package com.recon.commands;

public enum CommandNames {addtrack, skiptrack, displayqueue, joinchannel, setbotchannel, viewallgamecards, creategamecard, deletegamecard, getweblink
}


I don't see where in this code you're actually telling JDA about your list of commands

Discord Bot Commands (when not Teporary) can take up to an hour to update. Use temp commands guild.updateCommands().addCommands(Data)
for debbugging/testing
